# How do you say "to play Devil's advocate" in German?

Tags: phrase, phrase-request

In English, I use the phrase "to play Devil's advocate" quite often, it allows me to ask difficult questions without challenging the other person's position or status too directly.

The nicest translation I have found so far is this one (from [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/translation/playing+devil%27s+advocate.html)):

> Mal ein bisschen ketzerisch sein

> So let's play Devil's advocate for a moment and ask who might buy this fountain pen and in particular, why would one want to buy the latest product from Lamy?

> Sind wir mal ein bisschen ketzerisch und fragen: Wer könnte sich diesen Füllfederhalter kaufen, und, vor allem, warum sollte man sich dieses neueste Produkt aus dem Hause Lamy zulegen wollen?

As you can see, it allows us to be direct and maybe a bit cheeky, but still not be offensive.

EDIT - to clarify the question in response to feedback - I am looking for a phrase which is used commonly in everyday German, not necessarily a direct verbatim translation of the phrase "Devil's Advocate".

Comment: So, what is it you don't like about the translation you've found? Which aspect exactly is not covered by this or should be improved?

Comment: I could make the question even more "ketzerisch" like this: "warum sollte man sich dieses neueste Produkt aus dem Hause Lamy **überhaupt** zulegen wollen?"

Comment: This question is somewhat problematic, since it already points towards a simple solution, but appears as a bit of a mismatch even in English. *Devils advocate* suggests a more serious question than buying a pen.

Comment: @guidot Not necessarily. That example sounds like it could be asked of someone intending to bring a new pen onto the market. In that case, asking the question would imply that perhaps nobody would buy any of the pens, making it a pretty serious question. Context is everything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For the given context I would use:

> Ganz provokant gefragt: Warum... (Provocatively asked: why...)

*Überspitzt formuliert* would be an alternative. Both reduce the full sharpness by admitting it; this also means, that the speaking person does not necessarily share that point of view.

Comment: I think this is the best answer. "Des Teufels Advokat" and "Advocatus Diaboli" is very uncommon. Never heard that in my life in the everyday life.

Comment: @HeadhunterKev In regard to your anecdotic evidence, my anecotic evidence is 2 of 4 people in my office know "Advocatus Diaboli" oder "Anwalt des Teufels".

Answer (score 26):

Das lateinische *Advocatus Diaboli* ist ein im Deutschen durchaus geläufiger Begriff mit der gesuchten Bedeutung. Er wird zwar selten verwendet, es gibt aber immerhin einen Wikipedia-Artikel[1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advocatus_Diaboli) dazu.

Die entsprechende Redewendung wäre "[den] Advocatus Diaboli spielen". Also etwa:

> Ich spiele mal den Advocatus Diaboli und frage: ...

Comment: "den Advocatus Diabili spielen" ist eine völiig geläufige Redewendung. Vgl. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Advocatus_Diaboli. Na gut, vielleicht heutzutage nicht mehr ganz so geläufig, auch der Duden bezeichnet es als "bildungssprachlich" und Latein ist sowieso "out". Alternativ kann man sagen "die Rolle des Advocatus Diaboli einnehmen". Siehe auch https://interessante-fakten.de/98/Des-Teufels-Advokat.html

Comment: Auch die deutsche Übersetzung "des Teufels Advokat" ist nicht unbekannt. Vgl. https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~des%20Teufels%20Advokat%20sein&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte[]=rart_ou&suchspalte[]=rart_varianten_ou

Comment: @PaulFrost während ich die Antwort eher als Kommentar sehen würde, empfinde ich deinen Kommentar eher als Antwort ^^ . Deine Anmerkungen sollten hier hinzugefügt werden.

Comment: Es gibt einen Wikipedia-Artikel dazu, weil der Ausdruck ein Fremdwort, also eben nicht besonders geläufig ist.

Answer (score 18):

Geläufiger als der lateinische Begriff ist "Des Teufels Advokat".

Dabei betont man, dass nur die Rolle eingenommen wird, und es nicht die eigentliche Meinung ist:

> Ich spiele hier mal des Teufels Advokat und sage ...

Meines Erachtens nach ist diese Redewendung erst durch Film- und andere Übersetzungen als Anglizismus in der deutschen Sprache angekommen, vgl. hierzu auch [Des Teufels Advokat](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118971/)

Comment: Eine Suche im DWDS nach ["des Teufels Advokat"](https://t1p.de/ae96) und nach ["Advocatus Diaboli"](https://t1p.de/pu8g) stützt Deine These nicht unbedingt, dass die deutsche Redewendung geläufiger sei als der lateinische Ausdruck. Der lateinische Ausdruck ist zumindest für geschriebene Sprache relativ gut belegt, die deutsche Übersetzung allerdings gar nicht.

Comment: Als Variante würde sich auch "Advokat des Teufels" anbieten, was für mein Empfinden etwas weniger gestelzt klingt.

Comment: As a native speaker, i have never heard someone say that. Also, `ketzen` is probably known by more people than `Advokat`.

Comment: @marstato, was meinst du mit "ketzen"? Was soll das sein?

Comment: OP said the already thought of a formulation involving the word `ketzerisch`. `ketzen` would be is it's verb form (though not in the duden)

Comment: @marstato - I never heard of "ketzen".

Answer (score 1):

This is not a perfect fit but probably more common and in some contexts appropriate:

> Den Teufel an die Wand malen (Paint the devil on the wall)

A direct translation would be: Assuming the worst thing(s) that could happen

Example:

> So let's play Devil's advocate for a moment and ask how do we react if it does not work out.
>
> Ich male jetzt mal den Teufel an die Wand und frage was wir machen wenn es schief geht.

Comment: I don't think "So let's play Devil's advocate for a moment and ask how do we react if it does not work out." is the right way to use "Devil's advocate". Therefore I think, this answer is misleading.

Comment: voll valsch. Die übliche Wendung ist doch grade, "Jetzt mal doch mal nicht den Teufel an die Wand". Demnach hätte "Ich will nicht den Teufel an die Wand malen, aber ..." eine andere Bedeutung als erfragt wird. Allerdings fände ich diese Bedeutung gewissermaßen richtiger. Zwar kommt eine Entschuldigung zum Ausdruck, doch wenn es sich auf Luthers Erfahrung mit dem Tintenfass auf der Wartburg bezieht, ... was war da überhaupt los?

Comment: Yeah, this answer is really not correct. “Teufel an die Wand malen” is used more like “wenn man vom Teufel spricht”. Saying “ich male jetzt mal den Teufel an die Wand...” would mean: “I now dare taking the risk of actually making the worst-case come true”, whereas “let's play Devil's advocate...” would mean “I agree that the worst-case probably won't happen, but _to be prepared nevertheless_...”.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, now you are conflating another saying and I'm not sure that's historically correct. If I say it, I just mean "to be come pessimistic", or ca "a pro pos" respectively, in the broadest sense.

Comment: "Den Teufel an die Wand malen" does not fit here. It is used in cases someone else makes the worse possible prediction about possible results.

Answer (score -1):

In german we generally use "Advocatus Diaboli", but the other answers already said that. The fully german way of saying it is "Anwalt des Teufels", so something like "den Anwalt des Teufels spielen".

Answer (score -4):

*devil's advocate* has broader use than you alleged

In one way a good fit is

- **Salz in die Wunde streuen**, which is loosely translated as *insult to injury* (in-salt? haha), but as far as I can tell alludes to the painful method of wound desinfection using iodine salt, "Jodsalz". Playing devil's advocate can burn as well, and be justified.

but if you are really looking for a sentence adverb, there is no such construction in the German language, I'm affraid. In that sense, *Advocatus Diabolus* or *Salz in die Wunde* can't just be strewn into a conversation, but has to be packaged up in an elaborate phrase.

Well, "Ich fürchte, ..." might come close, but looses the antichristian intimidation you are looking for.

To conclude, you haven't really explained what you were looking for well enough. Context is key. A translation that covers all possible contexts and allows you to play dumb will be hard to come by.

Comment: That has a completely different meaning!

Comment: @Llewellyn. Indeed, that is just a pronoun! If I misunderstood, please explain.

Comment: PS: *that* is also a determiner